# How to make each div the size of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html

Assuming I have the following:

```
<div class="a" background-color="orange">
</div>
<div class="a" background-color="blue">
</div>
<div class="a" background-color="red">
</div>
```

How can I make it such....

These three divs somehow each get the size of the browser veiw) maintain the same size as the viewer's browser window such that when the user scrolls down, they will only see one color?

Comment: Class names [can't start with a number](http://stackoverflow.com/a/449000), and `background-color` isn't an attribute.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Wrong - in HTML5 id's and class names can be any character.

Comment: @Damascusi scroll in which direction horizontally or verticle? your div should place next to each other or under the previous one?

Comment: Vertical, under previous one.

Comment: @jtheman: I stand corrected, but `background-color=""` is still wrong.

Comment: google 'html element fit full screen' and it pops right up, also a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719452/how-to-make-a-div-always-full-screen/1720820#1720820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS and set `height: 100%` like this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/wsraN/

**Demo 2 with colors**

http://jsfiddle.net/KFuYM/

**Note**

As stated in the comments use a class to apply the background color. You can see an example in the second demo:

```
div.orange {
    background: orange;
}
```

with:

```
<div class="orange"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use CSS rather than html deprecated attributes.
Your css might be:

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.boxes {  
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

.orange {
background-color: orange;
}

.blue {
background-color: blue;
}

.red {
background-color: red;
}
```

While your HTML:

```
<div class="boxes orange"></div>
<div class="boxes blue"></div>
<div class="boxes red"></div>
```

There are so many ways to do this. I would say my code is one of the easiest.

Comment: div's are block level elements so the `display:block` is repetitive and unnecessary.

Comment: Agreed, I unnecessarily assumed such class could be apply to inline elements as well.