# Detect and Block UC Browser

Tags: javascript, wordpress, browser, user-agent

For my website running on Wordpress, I want to block readers accessing it from UC Browser.. I have come across some scripts that can block the usual suspects (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.). Is there a way I can detect UC Browser and block access via it?

Here are the details of UC Browser's User Agent:

1. http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/b/434TWLW
2. http://bit.ly/1YlL8fW

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you searched "block user agent"? See http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/security/block-unwanted-users-from-your-site-using-htaccess

Comment: Yep.. I did check it.. But not very sure of how do I use it, esp. for my use-case.. Also I was looking at using this WP plugin to get the job done but it supports FF, Chrome, Safari, IE and Opera only.. https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-browser-check/

Any suggestions to block access to UC Browser and show a pop-up / warning?

Comment: Does your server support .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*UCBrowser.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

It will block any browser which send `User-Agent` header containing string `UCBrowser`.

If you want to redirect all UCBrowser users to specific page, for example showing information that this browser is not supported, your `.htaccess` should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*UCBrowser.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* browser-not-supported.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @gothdo. Will try it out. It will be very helpful if you can guide me on how do I show a responsive pop-up to UC Browser users asking them to try some other browser when this block thing works (let's say chrome)... Something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j35o9yxtaudk9qw/screengrab-browser-check-pop-up.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Would have definitely loved to do that.. Unfortunately, my reputation on SO is still lesser than 15 (don't access it frequently but would that's something that I do intend to change). So, unable to upvote for now but have accepted your answer.. Thanks once again...

Comment: You can't rely only on the string "UCBrowser" as in the answer! There are variants out there in the wild with "UC Browser" http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=%22UC+Browser%22&include=yes&class=all&do=desc and also with the string "UCWEB" http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=%22UCWEB%22&include=yes&class=all&do=desc 
And they don't necessarily come together, so you have to test all three to get all variants of UC Browser...

Comment: How about nginx ? Do you have some example

Comment: @RobbNesp I think you should ask a new question about that.

Comment: After all searching i found this is the only answer which approved . I am looking for How can we block only moblie UC users not entire users (or) block from a specific resolution like <480px etc..

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this, this script will blocked old and latest all UCBrowser and redirect to custom page

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*UBrowser.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*UCBrowser.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* browser-not-supported.html [L]
```

Comment: I tried this. www.xyz.com gets the necessary block. But www.xyz.com.a.html opens easily. What to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat "simple", but not "too simple".

You may detect the browser using JavaScript Window Navigator. The window.navigator object contains information about the visitor's browser.

Refer here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp and you will find a demo here https://jsfiddle.net/wvbdnb8o/ which detects some common browsers using some code like;

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
```

Next, create a "mask" using html and css. I mean, A full screen, opaque `<div>`, that prevent readers from viewing the contents of page. You may refer this stackoverflow post [How to make a <div> always full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719452/how-to-make-a-div-always-full-screen).

When you detect UC Browser, display the mask, else, hide it. Hope this will give you a kick start.