# How to make a div cover the whole screen

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a question.

I got this so far: 
[image]

I basically want the highlighted div to cover your device screen no matter how big the device screen is. now i see 2 different divs when i open this on my phone. i only want to see the one that is highlighted. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance, 
kevin

Comment: Set body to `height:100%;width:100%` then `.textboxtransparent {height:100%;width:100%}`

Comment: Please share the code and create a fiddle showing the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a <div> always full screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719452/how-to-make-a-div-always-full-screen)

Comment: You can assign the height of viewport to `div` like `height: 100vh`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dfv4gdw3/ Js fiddle added

Comment: @Albzi This didn't work D:

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use viewport height as your height value:

```css
.main {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  CONTENT
</div>
```

Using height: 100vh means the element in question always be 100% height of the viewport a user / devie has.

More info: https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: @KevinAartsen happy to help!

Answer (score 7):

You can probably do that by setting the position of the div that you want to make fullscreen, to `absolute`and then apply the below CSS.

```
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
```

Thus, the final css would be as follows

```
.fullscreen{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed`.
Use `absolute` for just making it cover the whole page.
Use `fixed` to make it nailed in a default position. If you use `fixed`, even though your page is more than 100% you cannot scroll down to see any other things.

CSS

```css
div.any {
   position: absolute; /*position: fixed;*/
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   /*You can add anything else to this like image, background-color, etc.*/
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="any"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: fill;
}

.video-container video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```