# How do I make a container fill the whole page? Also to be responsive

Tags: javascript, html, responsive

I have different sections like "About me", "Contact", "Photo gallery" etc, and I want that when I open the site, the "About me" container to be displayed on the whole page, to fill the page without any content from the next section to appear.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-left">
 <div id="About me">
  <h1 class="margin">About me</h1>
  <p> My text here</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have the "container-fluid" class for every container with content in the index file.

```
.container-fluid {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `position:fixed;z-index:1;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;` make z-index the highest value if youve used it elsewhere. but going to need clearer instructions of what you actually need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a <div> always full screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719452/how-to-make-a-div-always-full-screen)

Answer (score 0):

That should addapt to the width of the browser at every state.

```
.container-fluid {
width:100%
padding:70px 0px 70px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [viewport relative units](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths).

```
.example {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give the about container a `height:100vh; width:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 .container-fluid {
     width:100%
     padding:70px 0px 70px 0px;
     margin :0;
  }
```

If above code not work write !important as like padding:70px 0px 70px 0px!important;
Sometimes old style not override by new style so you make it important by writing above statement.