# React Material UI Grid oversize full screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

working with [Material UI Grid](https://codesandbox.io/s/pp2p35q30q), this has oversize full screen and generate horizontal scroll bar, how to can fix it ?

```
const styles = theme => ({ root: { flexGrow: 1,}, paper: {  padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,textAlign: 'center',color: theme.palette.text.secondary,},});
```

generate like [horizontal scroll bar](https://codesandbox.io/s/pp2p35q30q)

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking. Do you think you could elaborate a bit, and include the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Find out that using `minHeight: "100vh"` solves this problem

```
root: {
  minHeight: "100vh",
}
```

[where i found this solution](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-to-make-div-take-up-full-screen/93742/2)

the bellow worked too:

```
root: {
  position: 'fixed',
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  zIndex: 10,
}
```

[where i found this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11982566/10832633)

Answer (score 0):

After too much test, I get solve this problem, change spacing 24 to 16, because childs has 12, I hope this helps someone

```
  <Grid container spacing={16}>
```

[Without horizontal scroll bar](https://codesandbox.io/s/0mznn9lvqw)