# Creating a full screen popup window and updating the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to create a full screen window using CSS, I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719452/how-to-make-a-div-always-full-screen).

My problem is that my full screen window is quite long, and I get a scroll bar inside the main page... would be possible create a full screen window in such a way that I see only one scroll bar? (i.e. use the main scroll bar for the full screen window when it is open)

```js
function toggleWindow() {
  $('.fullScreenWindow').toggleClass('show');
}
```

```css
.fullScreenWindow {
  display: none;
}

.fullScreenWindow.show {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="toggleWindow();">toggle window</button>
  <div class="fullScreenWindow">
    <br/><br/>
    <h1> full screen window start</h1>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <h3>getting 2 scroll bars</h3>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <button onclick="toggleWindow();">close</button>
    <h1> full screen window end</h1>
    <br/><br/>
  </div>
  <h4> some long page ...</h4>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <h4> some long page ...</h4>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <h4> some long page ...</h4>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <h4> some long page ...</h4>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <h4> some long page ...</h4>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding class on body tag with overflow: hidden when popup opens solve the problem i guess

Comment: @gowthamrajan: thanks a lot, that's a good solution... I just wait to see if I get any other alternatives.

Comment: Any specific alternative way you looking for?

Comment: I think your solution is really good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From a logical perspective**

this is a dynamic process, `body` has a scroll bar, and `Full Screen` has a scroll bar, you want to hide `body` scroll bar when `Full Screen` show. So there's a lot of solutions, I just give an example:

1. set basic style:

```css
    html, body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
```

2. change body scrollbar when `Full Screen` show

```js
function toggleWindow() {
  $('.fullScreenWindow').toggleClass('show');
  $('body').css({"overflow": "hidden"})
}
```

**From the perspective of implementation**

This is a very common requirement, No matter if your modal are full screen or not, each alert modal in our website has this feature. There are big amounts of libraries to do that, such as:

`Bootstrap`css style framework but also has some very practical JS component

`Ant Design` which contains a variety of components.

`SweetAlert2` which focus on the alert component,

They have better compatibility and style for this, you can try that