# Make a div fullscreen but with browser controls

Tags: html, css, html5-fullscreen

I have a div within my html5 app. I turn this div fullscreen using [fullScreenAPI](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/)

But what I want is the div to take full space only within the tab's content, so that all other browser controls are still available to the user. Is it possible?

Comment: Just resize the `div` and its child elements. Post your code please.

Comment: `position:fixed` & all four coordinates (top, left, …) set to 0 …?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like so? This works in Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #fs {
            min-height: 100%; 
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #fs {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="fs">content that fills the page</div>
</body>
```

If you have other content on the page that you want to hide, you can add z-index:

```
#fs { 
    z-index: 100 
}
```

Source: [How to make a <div> always full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719452/how-to-make-a-div-always-full-screen)