# get a div to fill the whole screen without position absolute or relative

Tags: html, css

I have got a problem, i need to make a div fill the whole screen using without any text inside it.
(Like when you make position absolute, width 100% and height 100% but without position absolute)
tnks :)

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23908106/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `width: 100vw; height: 100vh`

This means it will take whole viewport height and width